# Comparing stock indices using TradingChart

Tags: curated-data, finance, charts

Below I show a `TradingChart` specific to the SP500 index for a one month period. How do I  produce a similar plot where three other indices (ASX200, Shanghai Comp, Nikkei) can be compared without much overlap between the data associated with the different indices.

Here is the code that will generate the SP500 chart.

```
TradingChart[{"SP500", {{2015, 7, 24}, {2015, 8, 24}}}, {"Volume", 
  "SimpleMovingAverage", "BollingerBands"}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: It is not obvious what you mean by "without interference". How is the combined chart to look?

Comment: @Goldberg  What I mean is that the data for different indices do not interfere too much so as to make the visual presentation messy. It is OK if the graphs are placed side by side as an array if this is unavoidable. Importantly, what do I substitute for "SP500" for the other ones (ASX200, Nikkei etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy once one finds out the correct symbols for the various indices. I found them on Yahoo.

```
Column[
  TradingChart[{#, 
     {{2015, 7, 24}, {2015, 8, 24}}}, 
     {"Volume", "SimpleMovingAverage", "BollingerBands"}, 
     PlotLabel -> #, 
     ImageSize -> Medium] & 
   /@ 
     {"SP500", "^AXJO", "^SSEC", "^N225"}, 
   Spacings -> 1.5]
```

[image: charts]